# In ASP.NET Core, when you limit a request size, is the content still transferred to server and consume bandwidth?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, http, upload-max-filesize

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-6.0#multipart-body-length-limit) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits/), assuming I host the website on IIS server, I **should** put the below codes to limit/increase the upload size. My question is: do I actually need to set all of them? If my concern is to prevent someone from uploading a huge file, consuming server bandwidth (which costs money), which one is absolutely needed? Do all of them "short-circuit" a request if they upload a big file without even receiving it?

**web.config** (I give it 101MB limit since 100MB would not allow 100MB file due to headers etc):

```xml
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="105906176" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

**Kestrel config** (I put it just in case, I don't know if Kestrel is actually used if I host it on IIS):

```cs
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(opt =>
{
    opt.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = settings.MaxFileSize;
});
```

**Multipart config**

```cs
services.Configure<FormOptions>(opt =>
{
    opt.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = settings.MaxFileSize;
});
```

And finally the API Controller method:

```cs
    [HttpPost, Route("/test-upload")]
    public IActionResult TestUpload([FromForm] IFormFile file)
    {
        if (file.Length > this.settings.MaxFileSize)
        {
            return this.BadRequest("File size exceeded");
        }

        return this.Ok();
    }
```

I am making the project on IIS Express and I do not know how I can setup an environment that can test the above cases.

Comment: Testing is simple: attempt to upload a file larger than 101 MB.

Comment: @RobertHarvey yes that's what I am doing. I know the code works (because of different error pages) but I cannot know if the file is actually transferred.

Comment: Um, save the file?